# Passing parameter with value to a function does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a small application with Anular 9 and Angular Material. I have a list of items, each with an "Edit" button. I tried to pass the id of the item to the `editItem()` method, not "traditionally" (for security reasons), via the URL, but this way:

In the template:

```
<div class="item-name">{{node.item.name}}</div>
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="editItem($event, id:string = node.item.id)">Edit</button>
```

In the .ts file:

```
editItem(event, id): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Item id is: " + id);
}
```

Instead of the expected result, I get a `Missing expected ) at line <line number>` error.

What am I doing wrong? What is a (simple) working alternative?

Comment: You're *calling* a function, not *defining* it - `editItem($event, node.item.id)`.

Comment: If you want to define `id` as a string, do it in `editItem`, like `editItem(event, id: string): void { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments are suggesting, there's no concept of a named parameter in an Angular template. You define the function in the `.ts` file that is then called in the `.html` file.

You should call your function like:

```html
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="editItem($event, 
node.item.id)">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Does the console.log in the editItem function not show it? If you just need to see it to verify your code is working, you can display it right on the button >Edit {{ node.item.id }}</button>

Answer (score 1):

You are using type declaration in function. Just pass value only

use like this

```
(click)="editItem($event, node.item.id)"
```

Simply pass item Id in your function